# How to reuse/extend functions on Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to develop 2 `functions` with `Powershell`. The first, will check my database status (`online`/`offline`). The second function should loop on the first function until a certain state is achieve.

```
function Get-DBStatus
{
  <# .. removed help section for brevity .. #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [OutputType([System.Object])]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$ServerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$ServerUser,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$ServerPassword,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$DatabaseName,
  )

  try
  {
    $params = @{ ... }     
    $dbStatus = Invoke-SqlConnection @params | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $AltDBName }
  }
  catch
  {
    Write-Error -Message ('An error has occured while ...')
  }
  if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($dbStatus) -eq $false)
  {
    $dbStatus
  }

 # <<< function Get-DbStatusOnlyIf 
 # <<< same parameters as the function above
 # <<< get the desired status as a new parameter
 # <<< loop the function above until the desired status is achieved or a timeout is reached

}
```

I'm new to Powershell and I think I shouldn't repeat myself rewriting the same parameters from the first function into the second one since they're dependent. However, I might be wrong, thus the question.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but it sounds like rather than writing two functions you might want to write just one with a extra parameter to use for the conditional.

Comment: Hi @BenH, I would do that, however a friend of mine insisted creating two functions for that purpose. Perhaps, I should convince him of otherwise ? :D

Comment: Use whatever structure reduces complexity and increases efficiency. Look at all of the included cmdlets that have different parameter sets and flags. Sometimes it makes more sense to split out logic, sometimes it makes sense to combine. It depends greatly on the project. An example of a built-in cmdlet that would be a good analog is `Test-Connection`, it has a `-Quiet` parameter and a `-Count`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to rewrite this parameters on your second function and pass them through or add another paramter to your first function that will do the looping. I would go with the second solution.

Try something like that

```
function Get-DBStatus {
    <# .. removed help section for brevity .. #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Object])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerUser,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerPassword,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$DatabaseName,
        $WaitForStatus, #or something like that
        [int]$Timeout=10
    )
    do { 
        try {
            #$params = @{ ... }     
            $dbStatus = Invoke-SqlConnection @params | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $AltDBName }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error -Message ('An error has occured while ...')
            return
        }
        if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($dbStatus) -eq $false) {
            if ($WaitForStatus){
                if ($dbStatus -eq $WaitForStatus) {
                    $dbStatus
                    $EndLoop = $true               
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host -NoNewline "." #only for test   
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                    $Timeout -= 1                  
                }
            }
            else{
                $dbStatus
                $EndLoop = $true
            }
        }
    }
    until ($EndLoop -or $Timeout -eq 0)              
}
```

or with recursion

```
function Get-DBStatus {
    <# .. removed help section for brevity .. #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Object])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerUser,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerPassword,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$DatabaseName,
        $WaitForStatus, #or something like that
        [int]$timeout = 3
    )
    if ($WaitForStatus) {    
        $start = Get-Date
        while (((get-date) - $start).TotalSeconds -lt $timeout) {
            $res = Get-DBStatus -ServerName $ServerName -ServerUser $ServerUser -ServerPassword $ServerPassword -DatabaseName $DatabaseName
            if ($WaitForStatus -eq $res) {
                return $res
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1        
        }

    }
    else {
        try {
            $params = @{ ... }     
            $dbStatus = Invoke-SqlConnection @params | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $AltDBName }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error -Message ('An error has occured while ...')
        }
        if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($dbStatus) -eq $false) {
            $dbStatus
        }
    }

}
```